# Java code coverage tool on github without running on the local machine

Tags: java, github, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

Could `SonarQube`, `Jacoco`, or any other tool automatically run tests whenever I push to my repository, providing me with information if tests passed and code coverage information without running it on the local machine?

Comment: you need CI pipeline. Jenkins or Travis would be a good start

Comment: Yes it is possible, providing that you have good reason of not running the tests and checking the coverage on the local machine before the push